# SOAP api not accepting keys

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to get data out of a SOAP API (complexType) but it's saying that my provided data is incorrect.

**Errormessage I'm getting**: "Wrong combination LINKCODE/LINKHASH"
*(LINKCODE represents CompanyId & LINKHASH represents linkHash)*

The weird thing is though, when I'm trying to get data using http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html, it works...

Are there things I have to provide such as schemes or encodings?

Anyway, this is my code:

```
<?php
include_once 'getArticles.class.php';
$objGetArticles = new getArticles();
$objGetArticles->CompanyId = 'xxx';
$objGetArticles->linkHash = 'xxx';
$objGetArticles->SyncOnlyGlobalPrices = 1;
$wsdl = "https://wcupwebservice.syscom.be/wsWCupDemo/wsWCupDemo.exe/wsdl/IwsWCup";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,
  array (
    'trace'                   => 1,
    'exceptions'              => 0,
    'cache_wsdl'              => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'keep_alive'              => false
  )
);

try {
  $result = $client->getArticles(new SoapVar($objGetArticles, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
}catch (SOAPFault $f) {
  echo $f->getMessage();
}catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

getArticles.class.php:

```
<?php
  class getArticles{
    var $CompanyId;
    var $linkHash;
    var $SyncOnlyGlobalPrices;
  }
```

Anybody know what to do here? I've spent so much time on this already.. Thanks!